# Datatables remove CSS from DOM

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and data tables on a small div block.

The problem is, even though i have the datatables info turned off (bInfo) it still places the html in the DOM which is messing up my pagination.

Is there a way to not have it put in the html if you have it turned off?

[image: Datatable]

Here is my code that generates the data table

```
  $('#dashboardStats').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "iDisplayLength": 5
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just add:

```
"sDom": "t<'row'<'col-md-12'p>>"
```

in your javascript file. This will remove the info div altogether and make the pagination `col-md-12`

Comment: This is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by doing this:

```
$('.dataTables_info').parent().remove();
$('.dataTables_paginate').parent().removeClass('col-xs-6').addClass('col-xs-12');
```

This will remove the info section completely and then I changed the class of the pagination from spanning 6 to 12.